# Accessing a Property of an Object in an Array in an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm attempting to access a property of an object that is in an array within another object (within an array). The structure of the main object looks like so (where `readings` is an array of already constructed objects passed into the 'week' constructor):

```
function week(weektitle,readings){
this.weektitle=weektitle;
this.readings=readings;
}
```

I can create the array of readings, and I can access properties (such as `readingsArray[0].readingtitle`) before I pass it into the constructor (which I am doing as `weekArray[x]=new week(title,readingsArray)`).

However, I can't seem to access that same property once I pass the `readingsArray` into the constructor. From what I can piece together from forum questions about accessing properties of objects within arrays, it seems that, if my goal were to get the title of the first reading in the second week, I would have to chain something like this together:

```
weekArray[1].readingsArray[0].readingtitle
```

However, that's not working.

I'm a relative novice at javascript and jQuery, so I am thankful for any information you can provide! Also, if there is a more elegant way of building an array of weeks that each possess properties and contain an array of readings with properties, I'd be happy to hear about that, too!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I'm a fool - while editing my question to make it more clear, I realized I was using `readingsArray` (the name of the array before it is passed into the constructor) to try to access the property, instead of `readings` (the name of the array within the constructor).

Changed that, and it worked just fine.

Guess thinking "out loud" really does pay off sometimes!